# How can I hide/show an element when a button is pressed?

Tags: android, eclipse, hide

I'm trying to learn how to develop Android using the Eclipse IDE. What I'm trying to do right now is make a hidden TableLayout visible when a button is pressed. However, I have no idea as to what I need to put in the button's OnClick property.

Also, are there any tutorials online that could help me learn how to develop Android apps in Eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

well just take the reference of the TableLayout by using `findViewById(int)` in the `onClickListener()`. once you have the object of TableLayout, call `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Answer (score 14):

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findeViewById(R.id.yourtablelayout);

tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Something like that within your `onClick()` method should do the trick.

Comment: And does this go in (project name)/src/(package name)/(class name).java? If so, where should I put it?

Comment: It would go in whichever activity contains the button and TableLayout.

Comment: Would it be possible to find something by name, rather than ID?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
TableLayout table;
Button button;
table = (TableLayout) findViewById (R.id.tablelayout1);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // View list = (View)findViewById(R.id.myviewId); 
        tbleview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

    }
});
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in MainActivity class :

```
  TextView textview;
```

/* onClick method of show button */

```
  public void show(View view){
    textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

/* onClick method of hide button */

```
public void hide(View view){
    textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

and try this in onCreate method :

```
    textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
```