# How to show/hide some checkboxes in ListView

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I used `ListView` and `CheckBox` to create a checkbox `ListView` but I would like to show/hide some `CheckBoxes` by some cases. How can I do?

Comment: possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052288/how-can-i-hide-show-an-element-when-a-button-is-pressed

Answer (score 0):

Implements your own custom adapter may achieve what you want. 
Extend `BaseAdapter` and implement the abstract method `getView`.

```
public class YourListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    }
}
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html