# Gather parts from layout, java android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, sdk

Im pretty new at programming android and this is my problem:

I have a layout page that i have alot of information on, including buttons and textedits. Now i want to split it up in different parts, without having to create different layouts for every headline. So for example, if i choose to see "Information 3" i want to hide everything else on the layout except the "information 3 text/buttons/textedits".

Is it possible to do this? Because i really dont have time for making a new layout for every headline, and i dont want to show every headline at the same time. (I want to keep all information/data in the same layout file)

Maybe there is a smarter way to do it? Thanks in advance!
/Erik

Comment: You can use the same layout and hide whatever fields you want to on particular selection of information dynamically in you acticity.

Comment: Oh great, any suggested search words for google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call view.setVisibility(View.GONE) if you want to remove it from the layout. you can search some more questions like these:

1. [hide/show on click of Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052288/how-can-i-hide-show-an-element-when-a-button-is-pressed)
2. [how-to-show-hide-grouped-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852423/how-to-show-hide-grouped-views-in-android)

Try these and if u need more help then let me know

Comment: Hi again, my app crashes without eclipse showing any errors.
Im trying to do so that when you click on a button, your gonna be redicted to another layout + to show a hidden textview in that layout. This is my onClick code:

findViewById(R.id.textfield1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
startActivity(new Intent(ForthActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

Maybe the problem is that the textfield is in another layout, what do you think?

Comment: Hi,In which activity is your textView with id textfield1 ?